# How to force stop logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, logstash, centos5

I launched logstash via SSH on my server but there is an connection error to Elasticsearch. When I tried to CTRL+C Logstash did not stop and he is still running now. How can I force it to stop?

My server runs CentOS5

```
Got error to send bulk of actions to elasticsearch server at localhost : blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];[SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master]; {:level=>:error}
Failed to flush outgoing items {:outgoing_count=>552, :exception=>org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];[SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];, :backtrace=>["org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedException(org/elasticsearch/cluster/block/ClusterBlocks.java:151)", "org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedRaiseException(org/elasticsearch/cluster/block/ClusterBlocks.java:141)", "org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.executeBulk(org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/TransportBulkAction.java:210)", "org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.access$000(org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/TransportBulkAction.java:73)", "org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction$1.onFailure(org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/TransportBulkAction.java:148)", "org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$ThreadedActionListener$2.run(org/elasticsearch/action/support/TransportAction.java:137)", "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)", "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)", "java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)"], :level=>:warn}
SIGTERM received. Shutting down the pipeline. {:level=>:warn}
^CSIGINT received. Shutting down the pipeline. {:level=>:warn}
^CSIGINT received. Shutting down the pipeline. {:level=>:warn}
^CSIGINT received. Shutting down the pipeline. {:level=>:warn}
^CSIGINT received. Shutting down the pipeline. {:level=>:warn}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
initctl stop logstash
```

or If that not works then

```
systemctl stop logstash
```

or If that also not works

```
/etc/init.d/logstash stop
```

or

Do

```
ps -aux|grep logstash
```

to get all logstash process, and kill them as

```
kill -9 <process-id>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```bash
sudo systemctl status logstash
```

This command also provide useful additional information and logs.

The PID is written at `Main PID:`, then do as [YATIN GUPTA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4854263/yatin-gupta)

```bash
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```